# How to make child routes work in AngularDart?

Tags: angular, routes, angular-dart, angular-dart-routing

I have created a small repository with my problem: https://github.com/zegkljan/angular-dart-router-test

**What the app does** (or is supposed to do)

On the "home" page there is a list of items. You can click the items which brings you to a view of the item itself. In the item view, you have two buttons that, when clicked, show basic/advanced details of the item just below the buttons.

**Technical point of view**

`AppComponent` (the root component) has `<router-outlet>` which it uses to display a child component which is either an `ItemListComponent` (which displays the list, on path `/items`) or an `ItemComponent` which displays the item itself (on path `/items/:id`). The links in the item list use `[routerLink]` to navigate to the `ItemComponent`, and the `home` link at the top navigates to the `ItemListComponent`.

`ItemComponent` has its own `<router-outlet>` and a set of paths whose partent is the path to the item (i.e. `/items/:id`). Those paths are `/basic` and `/advanced` which are relative to the item's path (so a full path to basic details would be `/items/:id/basic`).

**What is the problem**

When clicking on the basic/advanced buttons, the `navigate()` method of the router returns `NavigationResult.INVALID_ROUTE` (and therefore no navigation) even though the url passed to `navigate()` (printed just before calling `navigate()`) is correct. If you clone/download the repo and run the app, open the browser console and observe.

What am I doing wrong, or what have I misunderstood regarding the AngularDart router and how child routes work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `RouterOutlet` directive (or `routerDirectives` which includes `RouterOutlet`) in the directives list of `ItemComponent` here: https://github.com/zegkljan/angular-dart-router-test/blob/master/lib/src/item/item_component.dart#L23